# Login or register in tabbed view

Tags: login, registration

I have a page that displays the login and register form in tabs so the user can choose either to register or login.

One is tab active only and currently it is the register tab because I'd like new signups. But what about the users who are already registered is it bad practice to leave register tab as active.

Which form should be active the login or register tab?

In addition, in any case what should be the title of the page link be? Should it be login/register or separate items for the same link?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you need to consider is, which tab will users use more often. You want to make your site as easy to use as possible for the largest amount of users. Clicking on a tab is an extra step, so you want to set up your page in a way that the fewest possible users will need to perform the extra step.

Usually, there are more users who already have an account than users who need to create new accounts. For this reason, I would make Login the default active tab. I would also move the Login tab to the first position.

As an example, if you try to ask a question on StackOverflow before you are logged in, you are taken to the following screen:

> [image]

As you can see, it defaults to the Log In tab since a user is more likely to already have an account.

Usually also, the Login tab has some sort of link directing users who don't  yet have an account and can't login, to the register page. I would suggest adding such a button or link to your Login tab if you don't yet have one. Then, if you think a large portion of users will need to go to the register page, you can always style it to make it stand out.

---

(On an unrelated design note, having all your tabs black with the selected one teal makes it hard to tell which tab is the selected active one. I would suggest changing your unactive (currently Login) tabs to white instead of black. That will make your teal active tab stand out more.)

Answer (score 0):

First, it depends on the platform analytics. Is it an old app and have a good amount of registered users who regularly use the application? Yes ?.. **Keep Login First.**

If you are launching a new platform or revamping an old one with new features to bring in more audience... **go for signup as the first tab.**

In either case, there must be **multiple points of navigating** to the other tab. One by clicking on the other tab itself. Other by navigating from a link present inside the tab window.

**Another suggestion on the design**. Giving Teal and Black colour to the tab does not indicate clearly which tab is currently selected. I would suggest you use white color for selected tab and merge it with the tab body. Use any other color for the second tab.